# I want to extract a value from a json

Tags: java, json

I want to extract a key and its value from json object. I am having a 3 objects in a json with parent child relation, named as 
1. Parent,
2. childOne_OfParent and
3. child_OF_childOne.
I want to extract all the value of "userQueryId" from child_OF_childOne and store into a string type variable.
How do I perform this. Thanks in advance.

My Json object is:

```
{
  "createdBy": "****",
  "dashboardId": 1,

  "childOne_OfParent": [
    {
      "createdBy": null,
      "dashboardSectionId": 1,

      "child_OF_childOne": [
        {
          "createdBy": "XYZ",
          "userQueryId": "283"
        },
        {
          "createdBy": "ABC",
          "userQueryId": "284"
        },
        {
          "createdBy": "AWS",
          "userQueryId": "285"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: I am trying in this way.  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(dashboard);
              JSONObject getSth = jsonObject.getJSONObject("child_OF_childOne");...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put your code into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the json to create a model java class like this. I used your json to create the class using the site [https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter](http://Codebeutify). You can give a classname of your choice in the Class_Name.

```
public class Class_Name {
 private String createdBy;
 private float dashboardId;
 ArrayList < Object > childOne_OfParent = new ArrayList < Object > ();


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getCreatedBy() {
  return createdBy;
 }

 public float getDashboardId() {
  return dashboardId;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
  this.createdBy = createdBy;
 }

 public void setDashboardId(float dashboardId) {
  this.dashboardId = dashboardId;
 }
}
```

Then you can use the Jackson to convert your json into a java object and access the data you want. Here jsonString is your json and the objResp is your object.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Class_Name objResp = mapper.readerFor(Class_Name.class).readValue(jsonString);
```

Here is a useful guide for that. [https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/](http://Jackson%20Json%20guide)

Answer (score 0):

The tool for these kind of tasks is [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath). It has xpath-like search capabilities.
Here is a working example of the given question

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String searchQueryIds = "$.childOne_OfParent[*].child_OF_childOne[*].userQueryId";
    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("c:/temp/test.json"))) {
        List<String> ids = JsonPath.parse(is).read(searchQueryIds);
        System.out.println(ids);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is pojo for json and jackson library available. It will return comma separated queryUserIds.

```
Parent parent = new ObjectMapper().reader(Parent.class).readValue(inputJson);

String userIds = parent.getChildOne_OfParent().get(0).getChild_OF_childOne().stream()
                                    .map(c -> c.getuserQueryId())
                                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```